# Single Query To Select Based On Parameters If Or not supplied

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-server-2012

I have used `SqlDataSource` and have a select query based on `District` & `Zone` as below

```
SELECT a.[committee_id] memberid, a.[membername], a.[memberemail], a.[memberdesignation], a.[membercreatedby],b.districtname AS district,b.districtid,c.zone_name AS zone,c.zoneid
FROM [committee_details] a
LEFT JOIN district_master b on b.districtid=a.districtid
LEFT JOIN zone_master c on c.districtid=a.districtid and c.zoneid = a.zoneid
WHERE (a.[membercreatedby] = 'director') AND ((convert(varchar,a.districtid) LIKE '%2%') AND (convert(varchar,a.zoneid) LIKE '%25%')) ORDER BY a.[committee_id] DESC
```

It's an inline query. I have tried above query but `not able to figure out` how to **Select condition based**.

I want if **district** supplied then Select according to District, if both **District & Zone** supplied then Select according to both & If **nothing supplied** then Select All. But should be in single query. How should I do this?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). And [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix your query so you are not using meaningless table aliases.  Use table abbreviations!  I would also drop all the square braces; they just make the query harder to write and to read.

Basically, you want comparisons with `NULL` in the `WHERE` clause.  I have no idea why your sample code uses `LIKE`, particularly columns that appear to be numbers.  Nothing in the question explains why `LIKE` is used for the comparison, so the idea is:

```
SELECT cd.committee_id as memberid, cd.membername, 
       cd.memberemail, cd.memberdesignation, cd.membercreatedby,
       dm.districtname AS district, dm.districtid,
       zm.zone_name AS zone, zm.zoneid
FROM committee_details cd LEFT JOIN
     district_master dm 
     ON cd.districtid = dm.districtid LEFT JOIN
     zone_master zm
     ON zm.districtid = cd.districtid AND
        zm.zoneid = cd.zoneid
WHERE cd.membercreatedby = 'director') AND 
      (cd.districtid = @district or @district is null) AND
      (cd.zoneid = @zone or @zone is null) 
ORDER BY cd.[committee_id] DESC;
```

If you were using `LIKE`, then I would phrase the logic like:

```
WHERE cd.membercreatedby = 'director') AND 
      (cast(cd.districtid as varchar(255)) like @district) AND
      (cast(cd.zoneid as varchar(255)) like @zone)
```

And pass in the patterns as `'%'` when you want all values to match.  This assumes that the columns in `cd` are not `NULL`.  If they can be `NULL`, then you want an explicit comparison, as in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question right then you can use parameters and compare to the column itself if the values are not supplied or not present.

try the following:

```
SELECT a.[committee_id] memberid, a.[membername], a.[memberemail], a.[memberdesignation], a.[membercreatedby],b.districtname AS district,b.districtid,c.zone_name AS zone,c.zoneid
FROM [committee_details] a
LEFT JOIN district_master b on b.districtid=a.districtid
LEFT JOIN zone_master c on c.districtid=a.districtid and c.zoneid = a.zoneid
WHERE (a.[membercreatedby] = 'director') 
AND b.districtname = isnull(nullif(@districtname, ''), b.districtname)
AND c.zone_name = isnull(nullif(@zone_name, ''), c.zone_name)
ORDER BY a.[committee_id] DESC
```